# A new kind of convergence

Tags: convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

Let $(X,d)$ be a connected metric space. We say a sequence $\{x_n\}_n \subseteq X$ is T-convergent to $x \in X$ if the following is true:

$$ \mbox{if} \;  a,b \in X \mbox{ and } d(a,x) < d(x,b) \mbox{ then } \exists N\; \forall n\geq N:d(a,x_n) < d(x_n,b) $$
Does it true that T-convergence implies convergence !?

Comment: What if $a$ and $b$ are two points in $\mathbb{R}^2$ separated by 7 units, and $x_n$ is a sequence describing a circumference of radius 1 about $a$? Is that possible?

Comment: @noether T-convergence corresponds most probably to the property above, **for every** (a,b).

Comment: I guess that for something like a square on a plane it must be true

Comment: Because if you assume that a sequence T-converges to $x$ but doesn't converge to $x$ in a usual sense, you'll next find a subsequence of this $\{x_n\}$ which converges to a different point $y$ (by compactness), and then you'll consider $[x,y]$, and for all $a,b\in(x,y)$ if $d(x,a)< d(x,b)$ then $d(y,b)<d(y,a)$, so the last inequality (for any two peculiar $a$ and $b$) will hold for all $x_n$ sufficiently close to $y$, a contradiction with $T$-convergence of $x_n$ to $x$

Comment: @Did , thank you very much for the clarification

Comment: @AlexWhite If (X,d) is compact.

Comment: @Did Yes, if $(X,d)$ is compact... Then the statement holds. Even if $X$ is not a subspace f a plane, (i.e. arbitrary compact connected metric space) (the argumentation has to be modified quite a bit)

Comment: @Stefan H. But does $d(x_n,x)<d(x_n,b)$ imply $d(x_n,x)<\epsilon$? Since $d($x_n$,b)$ needn't be $<\epsilon$?

Comment: @AlexWhite: Thanks for pointing out my mistake!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The result is false in general. Let $X=\ell_2$. For $n\in\Bbb N$ let $x^n=\langle x_k^n:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $$x_k^n=\begin{cases}1,&\text{if }k=n\\0,&\text{otherwise}\;.\end{cases}$$

Let $a=\langle a_k:k\in\Bbb N\rangle\in X$. Then

$$\|a-x^n\|=\left(\sum_{k\ge 0}(a_k-x_k^n)^2\right)^{1/2}=\left((a_n-1)^2+\sum_{{k\ge 0}\atop{k\ne n}}a_k^2\right)^{1/2}\longrightarrow\left(1+\|a\|^2\right)^{1/2}$$

as $n\to\infty$. Let $z\in X$ be the zero sequence, and suppose that $a,b\in X$ with $\|a\|<\|b\|$. Then $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\|a-x^n\|=\left(1+\|a\|^2\right)^{1/2}<\left(1+\|b\|^2\right)^{1/2}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\|b-x^n\|\;,$$

so there is an $m\in\Bbb N$ such that $\|a-x^n\|<\|b-x^n\|$ for all $n\ge m$. It follows that $\langle x^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ $T$-converges to $z$, but $\langle x^n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge to $z$; indeed, it has no convergent subsequence.